# Constructing a two 3-qubit state involving either X, Y or Z rotation gate

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

The goal is to construct the state

$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}|010\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|101\rangle$

Two issues I am facing:

1. What is a good choice for initial state?
2. What is a good choice for rotation operator?

Hints or assistance would be helpful.

Comment: How would you produce a state such as $(|000\rangle+|111\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I apply a H gate to the first qubit of an initial state $|000\rangle$. Then apply a CCNOT gate centered on first qubit where left-most is the first qubit.

Comment: Not ccnot. Two controlled-nots. So now, if you change Hadamard to a rotation that produces different amplitudes?

Comment: @DaftWullie Yes two CNOTs. A hadamad is produced by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[X+Z]$ and $X = R_{X}(\pi), Z = R_{Z}(\pi)$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but you might equivalently think of $R_Y(\pi/2)$ has having the same effect as Hadamard on $|0\rangle$.

Comment: @DaftWullie Thank you for the hints.
I used $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ for application to $|0\rangle$ to achieve the desired probability amplitude. Once this is done, the probability amplitude is teased from the $|000\rangle + |111\rangle$. From here, it's an application of X operator to the second qubit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is the following way.

Initialise 1 qubit in the $|0\rangle$-state and rotate along the $Y$-axis to
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}|0\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|1\rangle.
\end{equation}
Append two qubits in the $|0\rangle$-state, and apply a multi-CNOT gate between the 3 qubits: the control is the first qubit in the superposition state, the targets are the other 2 fresh qubits.This gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}|000\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|111\rangle.
\end{equation}
Apply an $X$-rotation to the 2nd qubit and you will find
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}|010\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}|101\rangle.
\end{equation}

Comment: I managed to work out a solution following Daftwullie's hint.